# verify multiple links are directed to right page

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm new to ruby. using watir i'm written scripts to check multiple links are being directed to the right page as below.

```
Link= ["Link", "Link1"]
Link.each do |LinkValue|      @browser.link(:text=>LinkValue).wait_until_present.click
fail unless @browser.text.include? LinkValue
@browser.back   
end
```

1. maintaining Linktext in an array
2. iterating with each linktext
3. verify
4. navigate to the previous page to start verifying with next linktext.

But the script is not working. it is not executing after first value

Comment: Question seems to be confusing for me. You are trying to click the link, If link doesn't present, then it throws the error, So it doesn't even goes to this line `fail unless @browser.text.include? LinkValue`. I will write the answer below that might fulfill your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Link= ["Link", "Link1"]
result=[]
Link.each do |LinkValue|
  if @browser.link(:text => LinkValue).exists?
    @browser.link(:text => LinkValue).click
    if @browser.url.eql?'ExpectedUrlhere'
      result=[LinkValue,'success']
    else
      result=[LinkValue,'failure']
    end
    @browser.back
  end
end

p result
```

This might help.

Comment: Hi Gopal, i coudnt understand if @browser.url.eql?'ExpectedUrlhere', can you please explain me that

Comment: @browser.back is not navigating back. can you please suggest

Comment: @Rohin You need to check whether you are reaching the right page,right? That's what I am checking the resultant url.

Comment: @Rohin when you click the link through `@browser.link(:text => LinkValue).click` this code, is it moving to the next page? If it moves, then browser.back surely work and bring you back to the page where you clicked the link.

Comment: Thank you, it is taking me to the page but not navigating back

Comment: Okay, `require 'watir'

b=Watir::Browser.new

b.goto 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watir'

b.element(:id,'nav-askquestion').click

b.back
` Try to execute this small code and check whether it's navigating back.

Comment: Hi Gopal, it is not navigating back, is it because of firefox??

Comment: Try with Chrome and check whether it's moving back, it's doing it's job then it's not a browser problem.

Comment: The result array will consist of the success and failure result, So If you print result array you can know which are the links allow you to reach the destination page. Give the expected url.

Comment: Thank you. but there are different url for each link

Comment: You said you would liked to verify whether it's reaching to a particular page,right?

Comment: sorry, each will be redirected to their corresponding pages

Comment: Okay and store the links and their urls in a array like [link,url] and then you can verify. Modify the above code according to your requirement.